# Emacs server/emacsclient won't connect

Tags: 18.04, emacs

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) on my Lenovo W541 laptop. Under this new installation, the emacs server & emacsclient functionality no longer works. Invoking "emacsclient" at the command prompt tells me

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
```

But when I try to server-start in emacs,

```
‘server-start’ is an obsolete command; use ‘gnuserv-start’ instead.
Server subprocess exited
You can run the command ‘server-start’ with M-x ser-s RET
Server subprocess exited
```

Is the solution just to (as suggested) install gnuserv instead?

**UPDATE 1**
In response to @waltinator 's suggestion, I enter ^H+f server-start and get the response:

```
server-start is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
‘server.el’.
(server-start &optional LEAVE-DEAD)
This function is obsolete;
use ‘gnuserv-start’ instead.
Use ‘gnuserv-start’ instead of this function.
Allow this Emacs process to be a server for client processes.
This starts a server communications subprocess through which
client "editors" can send your editing commands to this Emacs job.
To use the server, set up the program ‘emacsclient’ in the
Emacs distribution as your standard "editor".
--
Prefix arg means just kill any existing server communications subprocess.
```

But there is still no match for 'gnuserv-start', nor is it clear online how to install it (pages typically note that it should come installed with Emacs).  Thoughts?

Comment: I'd try `M-x gnuserv-start`

Comment: @waltinator - Yes, but when I try that the minibuffer tells me "[no match]" and refuses to do anything more.

Comment: Debugging `.emacs` is hard. Does `^H-f server-start` say `server-start is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
'server.el'.`? Do you have a file called `/usr/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/server.elc`?

Comment: @waltinator - I know Meta and I know Ctrl, but what is ^H?
The compiled 'server.elc' file does exist. Many thanks.

Comment: `^H` means "Hold down the `Ctrl` key while typing `H`.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator, see my updated comments above.

Comment: Did you even do an Internet search for "`gnuserv-start`"? Are you running XEmacs? Hint: Do an Internet search for "`gnuserv-start`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the solution was to put the following lines in my .emacs startup file:

```
(autoload 'gnuserv-start "gnuserv-compat"
         "Allow this Emacs process to be a server for client   processes."
         t)
(gnuserv-start)
(setq gnuserv-frame (selected-frame))
```

Then 'gnuclient filename &' opens 'filename' right into the main emacs buffer. Strange that 'emacsclient' no longer works, but... there you have it.